# Есть ли готовые CMS системы для дежурного оператора?

Tags: yii2, yii, cms, fat-free

Задача следующая: Нужно написать систему для записей дежурного оператора интернет провайдера.

То-есть когда звонит абонент мы можешь выбрать его адрес из уже имеющих в БД адресов и написать комментарий к поломке, после чего можно отметить что исправили и кто исправил - выбор из зарегистрированых пользоватилей.

Также возможность выбора абонента по адресу и посмотреть все его заявки и прорисовка графика с колвом обращения.

Раньше писал это все на F3 (FatFreeFramework), но исходники потерял вместе с HDD.

**Сейчас ищу готовые решения или хоть на половину готовые с открытым кодом**.

Если ничего не найду буду все писать уже на YII 2, если будут желающие помощь прошу на борт :)

Comment: "Раньше писал это все на F3 (FatFreeFramework), но исходники потерял вместе с HDD." - поэтому надо использовать систему контроля версий. То, что вы описываете, немного похоже на таск- или багтрекер, возможно, проще будет написать автоматическое создание клиента как проекта в редмайне, чем писать все с нуля.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все это можно реализовать на основе таскменеджеров и тикетных систем техподдержки. Например на основе otrs либо его более простом и малофункциональном аналоге. Вообще, это достаточно типовая задача, попробуйте поискать/поспрашивать у конкурентов.

Полезные ссылки:

- [Сценарии работы с OTRS](http://www.otrs.com/otrs-business-solution-for-better-customer-service/?lang=ru)
- [Детальнее на примере OTRS](http://habrahabr.ru/post/185702/)

далее мне моя репутация не дает разместить здесь ссылки, поэтому шифруюсь:

- Эту штуку хотя бы в общих чертах нужно знать, чтобы знать сначала что делать, потом как, а потом быстрее находить правильные инструменты: ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITIL
- О хелпдесках: www.helpdeski.ru/
- Тоже полезно знать, тем более многие хелпдески это поддерживают из коробки: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management_database